# Wrong Return in Django TruncWeek

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

TruncDate and TruncMonth Return Right Data , but when using TruncWeek the Data not return like i am using TruncMonth/Date

two function models using TruncDate and TruncMonth running well, and TruncWeek Should Running necessarily

`class TblogByDateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    groupby = serializers.CharField()
    total = serializers.IntegerField()
    class Meta:
        model = Tblog
        fields = ('groupby','total')`

Queryset :

`Tblog.objects.filter(status='success').annotate(groupby=TruncMonth('createtime',output_field=DateField())).values('groupby').annotate(total=Count('createtime')).order_by('-groupby')[:7]`

if i change the `TruncMonth` function to `TruncWeek` the code should Grouping By Week,

the result when i am using [Using TruncMonth](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pC6M.png) and [Using TruncDate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmHcl.png) this is the problem when [Using TruncWeek](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BKhM.png)

> The result when using TruncMonth and TruncDate, the TruncWeek should returning like this too ,

---

```
"results": [
    {
        "groupby": "2019-08-01",
        "total": 77
    },
    {
        "groupby": "2019-07-01",
        "total": 24
    }
"results": [
    {
        "groupby": "2019-08-06",
        "total": 29
    },
    {
        "groupby": "2019-08-05",
        "total": 6
    },
    {
        "groupby": "2019-08-04",
        "total": 4
    },
    {
        "groupby": "2019-08-03",
        "total": 4
    },
    {
```

> When Using TruncWeek

---

```
"results": [
    {
        "groupby": "2019-08-05",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "groupby": "2019-08-05",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "groupby": "2019-08-05",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "groupby": "2019-08-05",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "groupby": "2019-08-05",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "groupby": "2019-08-05",
        "total": 1
    },
    {
        "groupby": "2019-08-05",
        "total": 1
    }
```

Comment: Please post code fragments, not images. Copy the result as text.

Comment: At first sight it looks like you dropped the `.order_by('groupby')` part.

Comment: i just change the TruncMonth/Date to TruncWeek,

Comment: Same issue when you use `Trunc('createtime', kind='week', output_field=DateField())`? I cannot reproduce your issue using Django 1.11, works for me. (TruncWeek was added in Django 2.1, not testing that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i change the`TruncWeek('createtime',output_field=DateField())` to `.TruncWeek('createtime')` and its worked for me,

i think the problem is using `groupby = serializers.CharField()` and `outpufield using DateField`